# How to run loop python script without interrupting

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I have written a python script to fetch the data from MQTT, It's working fine, the problem is after a month or so, It automatically stops getting the data from MQTT, and when i restart the script then it again start working. What will be the best approach to run the script so that it will work continuously?

PS: I have tried running through bash but still I have faced the same problem. Even though I have run through Monit but even that didn't solved the issue and in monit it shows the script is running.

My Script is :

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
import base64
import sqlite3
import datetime
import requests

APPID  = ""
PSW    = ''


def on_connect(mqttc, mosq, obj,rc):
    print("Connected with result code:"+str(rc))
    mqttc.subscribe('+/devices/+/up')

def on_message(mqttc,obj,msg):
    file1 = open('weather.txt','a')
    try:
        feed = json.loads(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
        print(msg.payload + '\n')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass

def on_publish(mosq, obj, mid):
    print("mid: " + str(mid) + '\n')

def on_subscribe(mosq, obj, mid, granted_qos):
    print("Subscribed: " + str(mid) + " " + str(granted_qos))

def on_log(mqttc,obj,level,buf):
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    print("message:" + str(buf))
    print("userdata:" + str(obj))


mqttc= mqtt.Client()
mqttc.on_connect=on_connect
mqttc.on_message=on_message
mqttc.on_subscribe=on_subscribe
mqttc.on_log=on_log

mqttc.username_pw_set(APPID, PSW)
mqttc.connect("eu.thethings.network",XXXX,XX)

# and listen to server
run = True
while run:
    mqttc.loop()
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

For client connect run forever use forever

**mqttc.loop_forever()**

May this hope will help.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
import base64
import sqlite3
import datetime
import requests

APPID  = ""
PSW    = ''


def on_connect(mqttc, mosq, obj,rc):
    print("Connected with result code:"+str(rc))
    mqttc.subscribe('+/devices/+/up')

def on_message(mqttc,obj,msg):
    file1 = open('weather.txt','a')
    try:
        feed = json.loads(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
        print(msg.payload + '\n')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass

def on_publish(mosq, obj, mid):
    print("mid: " + str(mid) + '\n')

def on_subscribe(mosq, obj, mid, granted_qos):
    print("Subscribed: " + str(mid) + " " + str(granted_qos))

def on_log(mqttc,obj,level,buf):
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    print("message:" + str(buf))
    print("userdata:" + str(obj))


mqttc= mqtt.Client()
mqttc.on_connect=on_connect
mqttc.on_message=on_message
mqttc.on_subscribe=on_subscribe
mqttc.on_log=on_log

mqttc.username_pw_set(APPID, PSW)
mqttc.connect("eu.thethings.network",XXXX,XX)
mqttc.loop_forever()
```

Happy Coding folk.